# How to send notifications to Microsoft band through background task and also how to identify any Uwp app whether notifications received or not?

Tags: microsoft-band

I am working on Microsoft band technology, in one of my scenario I want to send notifications to band through the background task.

I have a one UWP app, in that I was already implemented to send push notifications to other mobile numbers, in the same app I was implemented the concept as to connect Microsoft band, up to now no issues.

Next I am thinking how to send push notifications to band through background task and also how to know whether notifications received or not.

Please tell me How to Send Push notifications to band through background task?

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

There's little difference using the Band SDK from a background task than from the foreground.  If you already have the background task working for processing push notifications, you can simply use the Band SDK to connect to the Band and send a message or dialog.  The API will throw exceptions if it wasn't able to connect to the Band or was unable to send the message or dialog.

Beyond that, you'll need to be more specific about what you've tried and what specific problem(s) you've encountered.